# python syntax to access multiple names in the same namespace without repeating the name (like "using" in some languages

Tags: python

is there a way in python to tell the interpretes a bunch of statements should all be executed on the same object/namespace?

In some other languages you have constructs like

```
using myObject{
    .a = 1;
    .b = 2;
    .c = 3;
}
```

as shorthand notation for

```
myObject.a = 1;
myObject.b = 2;
myObject.c = 3;
```

Is there anything similar in python?

Something like

```
mo = MyObject()
using mo:
    .a = 1
    .b = 2
    .someMethod("whatever")
```

or

```
import testmodule
using testmodule:
    .target = MyObject()
    result1 = .test1()
    result2 = .test2()
```

Comment: For the `MyObject` example ... no. For the module import you can `from testmodule import target, test1, test2`

Answer (score 0):

you could manually update the **dict** attributes which hold all the attributes

```
attr = {'target': MyObject,'result1': test1(),'result2': test2()}
testmodule.__dict__.update(attr)
```

however this is kind of hack, better to add a method inside you testmodule which gets this as input (like dic) and update (setattr) to avoid problem and be able to check if needed.

and if you want to use this pattern frequently as well you could as well use the "with" statement, which in that case you have to implement `__enter__, __exit__` method and then you would write something like:

```
with testmodule as ts:
    ts.target = test() 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this in Python unless you define a setter function that returns `self`.
For example:

```py
class Class:
    values = []

    def add_value(self, value):
        self.values.append(value)
        return self


obj = Class()
(
    obj.add_value(1)
    .add_value(2)
    .add_value(3)
    .add_value(4)
)
print(obj.values)
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```